# Linear Operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Here is a question that I cannot figure out myself: Let $H$ and $K$ be separable Hilbert spaces (possibly infinite-dimensional), and $\lbrace e_i\rbrace_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be the orthonormal basis for $H$.  $T: H \to K$ a $\textbf{linear operator (not necessarily bounded)}$ such that $$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\vert\vert T(e_i)\vert\vert_{K}^2< \infty$$ Where $\vert \vert \cdot\vert\vert_{K}$ is the norm of $K$ induced by inner product. $\textbf{Prove or disprove}$ that $T$ is a bounded linear operator.

The key problem here is that I cannot passage the limit, i.e., $T(\sum\limits_{i}e_i) = \sum\limits_{i}T(e_i)$ may not hold. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Consider $v=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n \in H$, this means $\Vert v \Vert_H^2=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \vert a_n \vert^2<\infty$ and thus, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $$ \vert T(v) \vert = \vert \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n T(e_n) \vert \leq \Vert v \Vert \left( \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert T(e_n) \Vert_K^2\right)^{1/2}.$$ This gives you that $T$ is a bounded operator. These kind of operators are called Hilbert-Schmidt operators and they have some nice properties.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven But $T$ may not be bounded. Can you passage the limit out to say $T(v) = \sum_{n} a_nT(e_n)$?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, it is not quite as simple.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven This is a homework question from my analysis course. I'm not sure if the statement is correct. I'll change it to "prove or disprove" in case the statement itself is wrong. Thank you anyway!

Comment: The statement is not true. One would need to rephrase it in such a way that $T$ is defined in the form I was using.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Can you give any counter-example?

Comment: I can :) see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is somewhat surprising, but in fact the statement is not true.

**Counterexample:** We know that $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are linearly independent. Thus, we can extend this to a basis $(e_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \mathbb{N}\cup \Lambda}$ of $H$. As the Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is not countable (by Baire's theorem), we know that there exists a countably infinite subset $S\subset \Lambda$ and we can wlog write $S=\mathbb{Z}_{<0}$. Pick any $0\neq w_0\in K$ and define $A$ to be the linear extension of

$$ A(e_\lambda)= \begin{cases} T(e_\lambda),& \lambda \in \mathbb{N},\\ \vert \lambda \vert w_0,& \lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0},\\ 0,& \text{ otherwise.} 
 \end{cases} $$

This operator $A$ is by definition linear, it is unbounded (as $\vert A(e_{-n}) \vert = \vert n \vert \cdot \vert w_0 \vert \rightarrow \infty $ for $n\rightarrow \infty$) and we have
$$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert A(e_n) \Vert_K^2 = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert T(e_n) \Vert_K^2 < \infty. $$

**A true version:** The following statement would be correct: If $T:H \rightarrow K$ is such that for all $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n \in H$
$$ T(\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n T(e_n) $$
and
$$ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert T(e_n) \Vert_K^2 <\infty,$$
then $T$ is a bounded operator (simply by Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact that $\Vert \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n \Vert_H^2 = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \vert a_n \vert^2$). In fact, in this setting, $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and thus even compact.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}e_n.$ Then the set $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent. This set can be extended to the Hamel basis of $\mathcal{H}.$ Fix a nonzero vector $u\in K.$ Let $Tx=\lambda_v(x)u$ where $\lambda_v(x)$ is the coefficient corresponding to $v$ in the expansion  of $x$ with respect to  the Hamel basis. Then $Te_n=0.$ The operator $T$ is unbounded. Indeed if it was bounded then $T$ would be equal $0,$ as it  vanishes on the orthonormal basis.

Comment: That's a really neat construction! The entire choice is outsourced to the basis and we do not need to bother at all about picking any particular values.